# webform submission in drupal 7 web site

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform, drupal-form-submission

I have installed the Webform module for my drupal 7 web site. It works well, but when I click the submission button without filling the form, it goes to a page which shows the resuld when I want to reload the same webform. How do I set the path to load the page which the webform included when clicking submit button without filling the form?

Comment: If you don't want people to submit an empty form, can't you make the fields required? That would bring them back to the same page and throw an error. Or do you want to have people submit the same form several times?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set a custom page in node/XXX/webform/configure (advanced parameters) and from there you can validate the webform.

you can also do it with [webform_validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) and deny submit button when form is empty

hope it helps

PR